# On gcc path searching - I'm not able to import files on current dir

Tags: c++, gcc, path, g++

I'm a guy who came from python to cpp. I barely have any experience with `gcc` compiler.

The problem I have is;

if I have `foo.h` under `somedir`. Compiling `bar.cpp` by g++/gcc can't find `foo.h` unless I include the absolute path.

some metadata

```
os : ubuntu 20.04 LTS
gcc version : gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

(note: I have tried `gcc -B . bar.cpp` but doesn't work)

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)?

Comment: As I'm not familiar with these stuff, I find it hard to point exactly what I need.

Comment: One thing you need to know is that C and C++ are different languages.  Compile C source with a C compiler such as `gcc`.  Compile C++ source with a C++ compiler, such as `g++`.  Know which language you are writing in, because it matters.

Comment: You need to spend several days in reading documentation, and looking for inspiration inside the source code existing open source projects (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [fish](https://fishshell.com/)...) You want to compiler with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` probably, and perhaps some `-I` arguments

Comment: As for the actual question, it would be easier to formulate an answer if you present a [mre], including the source and header, details of their relative layout on the filesystem, and the command you are using to compile.

Comment: can't `gcc` also compile c++ if for `-x` the the argument is given `c++`. Anyway, I am using `g++`, but as they come in the same package and has the same version, I thought of including only `gcc`. Sorry if I ambiguated anything

Comment: Generally speaking, do not use `gcc`'s option `-x`.  It is very unusual to do so, and it will confuse people.  Maybe even you.  The GCC system has a language-specific front end for each language it supports, except C, for which `gcc` (without `-x`) serves. These are what are normally used.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I generally don't tend to do so. I use `g++`.  Anyway, I think it would be super helpful if someone could point me out to any sort of elaboration or explanation of how `gcc/g++` does path searching.

Answer (score 1):

If the `*.h` file is in the same directory as the `*.cpp` file then `gcc` will find the file automatically in that same directory so you can use this command.

```
gcc bar.cpp
```

If the `*.h` file is in a different directory as the `*.cpp` file then `gcc` needs to be given more information where is the header file located, so you need to give the absolute path to the `-I` option.

```
gcc -I somedir/foo.h bar.cpp
```

Please note that in both these cases you can just write `#include "foo.h"` and the code will just work. In the first case `gcc` will be able to find the file because it is in the current working directory. And in the second case `gcc` will be able to find the file because it was given the absolute path to the directory where that file is located. You only need to specify the name of the file in the `#include` not the path since `gcc` already knows the path.